# Callable Command Design Pattern Solution For Below Code

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have code block like below and I want to escape from repeated code with Callable design pattern. Is it possible?

```
    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserRules(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String integId = helper.getIntegId(request);
        String orgId = helper.getOrgId(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getUserRules(integId,    orgId));
    }

    @GetMapping("/{ruleId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getRule(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable Long ruleId)
    {
        String integId = helper.getIntegId(request);
        String orgId = helper.getOrgId(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getRule(integId, orgId, ruleId));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{ruleId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateRule(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable Long ruleId,
                                        @RequestBody @Valid Object object)
    {
        String integId = helper.getIntegId(request);
        String orgId = helper.getOrgId(request);
        service.updateRule(integId, orgId, ruleId, object);
        return ApiResponse.ok();
    }
```

And I want to try execute it with Callable method.

```
public ResponseEntity execute(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ? Actually, I could not find an exact solution here.
}
```